# Taking name of field to update (not just value) from variable in calling JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to support variables all around to push changes to JSON

```
changeField=.one.aaa
changeValue=new-val
```

This works:

```
jq --arg changeValue $changeValue ".one.aaa = \"$changeValue\"" some.json
```

This does not:

```
jq --arg changeField $changeField --arg changeValue $changeValue "$changeField = \"$changeValue\"" some.json
```

I've tried every combination of `[{(` Google shows me, but nothing is working. What am I missing here?

Comment: What does your JSON actually look like? Is it a dictionary with `{".one.aaa": "old-value"}`? Or is it `{"one": {"aaa": "old-value"}}`? This is a place where a [mcve] is helpful rather than relying on people to make assumptions about your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you want the dots to be treated as nesting separators

This means letting JQ parse your `changeField` content as code; be certain it's from a trusted source. (By contrast, `changeValue` is purely passed as data out-of-band from code, preventing injection attacks no matter its contents).

```
inputJson='{"one": {"aaa": "old-val"}}'
changeField=.one.aaa
changeValue=new-val

jq --arg changeValue "$changeValue" "$changeField"'=$changeValue' <<<"$inputJson"
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  "one": {
    "aaa": "new-val"
  }
}
```

---

#### If you want the dots to be literal

```
inputJson='{".one.aaa": "old-val"}'
changeField=.one.aaa
changeVal=new-val
jq --arg changeField "$changeField" \
   --arg changeValue "$changeValue" \
   '.[$changeField]=$changeValue' <<<"$inputJson"
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  ".one.aaa": "new-val"
}
```

---

Note that when we passed an argument in through `jq --arg`, we used single quotes in the later query referencing it to make the reference a *literal* string to the shell, and thus syntactic to `jq`.

By contrast, when we wanted data (not the reference to it) to be syntactic to `jq`, we passed the variable's expansion in double quotes at the shell layer so it was expanded before `jq` parsed it as code.

Comment: Ahh so simple I can't believe I missed it! Thank you!!